# vb.net search the sql database to validate a customer account number

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, validation

Group, forgive me for what may be a very simple explanation and answer.  However I'm self teaching myself Visual Basic and very new to this altogether.  So you know, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express.

I've created a database that includes a customer records table.  Via the order entry module I'm working on, I want to allow the user to key in a customer account number.  However I need to validate this entry before proceeding with the rest of the program routines.  I THINK I know how to connect to the database, but I'm not sure how to have the user entered number compared against the table to validate the customer number.  Here is what I've written:

```
            Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            Dim dbSource As String = "Data Source = DataDesign.mdf"
            Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=SQL Server 10.0.5500;"
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM AR_CUSTOMERS"
            Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
            conn.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource 
            Dim search1 As Integer = Integer.Parse(txbCustomerNo.Text)
            Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
            conn.Open()
```

I'm now stuck.  I've defined my "search" (search1), but how do I now tell the program to look through the table to see if there is a matching customer number?

I hate to ask you to help me write the code.  But I'm clueless here and I've not been able to find a good example to help me understand the process and write the code myself.

If you see any syntax errors, don't hesitate to speak up!!

---

Based on some of your answers and further research, I've modified my code.  It now reads:

```
  Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection
  Dim dbSource As String = "Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Don\Documents\DataDesign.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
  Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=System.Data.SqlClient;"
  Dim ds As New DataSet
  Dim sql As String = "SELECT FROM AR_CUSTOMER"
  Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
  conn.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
  Dim search1 As String = "%" & txbCustName & "%"
  Dim sqlQ1 As String = sql & " WHERE ARC-CUSTOMER-NAME LIKE search1"
  Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(sqlQ1, conn)
  conn.Open()
```

Hopefully this syntax (search) looks better and more accurate.  If not, please help me correct it.

Assuming this is correct, what command codes do I need to get the full ARC-CUSTOMER-NAME (and there could potentially be multiple finds) as well as the corresponding ARC-CUSTOMER-NUMBER(s)?  I'm assuming that this data would go into two strings (do I need to "Dim" these to receive the data?) so that it could be put into the checkbox(es) and textbox(es) on the form.

I'm sorry I don't understand this better.  I'm hoping through this the lightbulb in my head will finally come on!!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM AR_CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerID = '12345'`. Read more on SQL and ADO.Net

Comment: @codingbiz if all you need to do is check that the `CustomerID` is valid, a `SELECT *` is wasteful (and a good way to annoy your DBA). `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM AR_CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerID = '12345'` would be better.

Comment: Good point. But that could get the OP confused too. Just building on the existing query in the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just interested to find if the customer exist or not in the database, you could write code like this

```
Using conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AR_CUSTOMERS WHERE customerNo = @custNo")
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custNo", Convert.ToInt32(txbCustomerNo.Text))
    Dim result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
    if Convert.ToInt32(result) > 0 then
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Found")
    End If
End Using
```

the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method of the SqlCommand object could be used if you are interested to find just a single row with a single result and it is usually very fast in cases like this.

Apart from this, I'm very perplexed by your connection string. It doesn't seems to be a valid one.
Here you can find numerous examples of connectionstrings valid for Sql Server: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

**EDIT**
Based on your comment it si now clear that a simple ExecuteScalar is not enough. We should use a SqlDataReader and use an ExecuteReader. Of course the query is completely different

```
Using conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerNo, CustomerName FROM AR_CUSTOMERS " + 
                              "WHERE customerName LIKE= @custName")
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", "%" + txtSearchText.Text.Trim() + "%")

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    If Not reader.HasRows Then
        txbCustName.Text = "No customer found!"
    Else
        While reader.Read()
           txbCustName.Text = reader(0).ToString
           cbxCustNo.Text = reader(1).ToString
        Loop
    End If
End Using
```

However this approach has its problems. What if the search using LIKE returns more than one rows? In this case your textboxes will be filled with the values of the latest customer found.
Perhaps it is better to use a DataTable and, if there are more than one customer ask the user to select from the available ones

```
Using conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerNo, CustomerName FROM AR_CUSTOMERS " + 
                              "WHERE customerName LIKE= @custName")
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", "%" + txtSearchText.Text.Trim() + "%")

    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
    Dim table As DataTable = new DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    If table.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        txbCustName.Text = "No customer found!"
    Else if table.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        Dim row as DataRow = table.Rows(0)
        txbCustName.Text = row("CustomerName").ToString
        cbxCustNo.Text = row("CustomerNo").ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("More  than one customer found!")
        ..... code to show the table in a datagridview .... 
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: Let me try better to explain what I'm doing this way:  The FORM Textbox contains a portion of the Customer's Name (it could be a last name).  Thus the % wildcard.  Let's assume the user types in "Williams" into that Textbox.  I now want the code to go search the AR_Customer table and look into the Customer Name column and find "Williams".  When it finds it, I need to move the full customer name into a textbox (called "txbCustName") along with that customers account number that needs to be moved into a checkbox (called "cbxCustNo").  I hope this helps.

Comment: I'll read through your link.  Hopefully I'll find something there that will help. I'm not sure what 'ExecuteScalar' means or does.  Working with databases is more foreign to me than Visual Basic is.  And I'm a newbie at that too.

Comment: Well this change a lot on my assumptions about your original question. I will try ti update my answer later. (You need a SqlDataReader or a SqlDataAdapter going with a modified version of your SqlCommand string)

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  I truly wish I understood this better.  But this is my first real entry into the world of the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be writing sql query already filtering by costumer number...  SELECT * FROM AR_CUSTOMERS WHERE costumerNo = txbCosumerNo.Text, and then you can use DataSet to store data retrieved from DataBase... (following your code..)

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
da.fill(data);
```

... you can get a DataTable from data.. (DataSet is a collection of DataTables), could be easy to work with.